# Problem with qgankgyefx..vbe virus

Tags: windows, virus

I am not sure if I am in right forum.
But i am having problem with this virus.
On affected computer, If we use a USB drive, all the file become hidden.
I am using HFV.exe for retrieve all data in pendrive, but still same thing happening for another pen drive.
any solution for removing this virus from computer?
tried malewarebyte, but doesn't work properly.
any help?
easy way to reinstall windows, but it will wipe out everything on my computer.
:(

Comment: Search for "YOUR_PREFERRED_ANTIVIRUS livecd"? LiveCD is a bootable disk (at least in the Linux world), so you can analyze the system while it's off.

Comment: I would go with what @FranciscoPresencia said. This is the best approach to clean the PC

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I downloaded this:
http://support.kaspersky.com/us/viruses/rescuedisk
now running it and detecting lot of virus there.
Thanks for excellent suggestion.
Hopefully my computer will be virus free.
Thanks